# Infinite loop when iterating through possible passwords

Tags: c, cs50

I wrote an admittedly ugly program to crack by brute force a password of up to 5 alphabetical characters that is hashed by the DES-based crypt() function, but when run the program results in an infinite loop. I cannot identify the cause. Does anyone see where I'm going wrong? I'm just asking about the infinite loop, though I'd certainly appreciate advice on alternatives to the nested for loop approach.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// function to check for equality between hashed try and user-inputted hash
int check_password(string key_try, string hash);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // check for 1 command-line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./crack hash");
        return 1;
    }

    string hash = argv[1];

    // create array of all alphabetical characters, upper and lower case
    char alpha_characters[52];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        alpha_characters[i] = i + 65;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        alpha_characters[i + 26] = i + 97;
    }

    // hash all possible passwords until hash of try matches user-inputted hash
    int password_found = 0;
    char possible_password[6];
    while (password_found == 0)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 52; j++)
        {
            possible_password[0] = alpha_characters[j];
            possible_password[1] = '\0';
            password_found = check_password(possible_password, hash);
            // iterate through second character
            for (int k = 0; k < 52; k++)
            {
                possible_password[1] = alpha_characters[k];
                possible_password[2] = '\0';
                password_found = check_password(possible_password, hash);
                // iterate through third character
                for (int l = 0; l < 52; l++)
                {
                    possible_password[2] = alpha_characters[l];
                    possible_password[3] = '\0';
                    password_found = check_password(possible_password, hash);
                    // iterate through fourth character
                    for (int m = 0; m < 52; m++)
                    {
                        possible_password[3] = alpha_characters[m];
                        possible_password[4] = '\0';
                        password_found = check_password(possible_password, hash);
                        // iterate through fifth character
                        for (int n = 0; n < 52; n++)
                        {
                            possible_password[4] = alpha_characters[n];
                            possible_password[5] = '\0';
                            password_found = check_password(possible_password, hash);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
    return 0;
}

// check hash of possible passwords against parameter hash
int check_password(string key_try, string hash)
{
    if (strcmp(crypt(key_try, "50"), hash) == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", key_try);
        return 1;

    }
    else
    {
       return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: I haven't used SO much. If my question is asked poorly, I'd appreciate guidance on how to ask better questions instead of just a downvote.

Comment: Which loop in your program is looping infinitely?

Comment: Most of your assignments to `password_found` are "dead": You never check the value before overwriting it with the next `check_password()` call.

Comment: looks like  may be you have problem  with your `check_password` function, it may be returning 0 each time you call it.

Comment: 1. What makes you think there is an infinite loop problem? Nesting five loops each with 52 loops is 52^5 or 380,204,032 `check_password ` calls is time consuming. 2. Use a debugger or even print statements.

Comment: @zaph You were right. The print statements revealed this was a more time-consuming process than I realized. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way code terminates is if the *last* call to `password_found = check_password(possible_password, hash);` in `for (int n = 0; n < 52; n++)` returns 1.

---

Add in 5 places

```
password_found = check_password(possible_password, hash);
// Add some means to exit the nested loops
if (password_found) return 0;
```

or...

In 5 places

```
 //       v--- j,k,l,m,n
 for (int x = 0; password_found == 0 && x < 52; x++)
```

---

And remove

```
// while (password_found == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `while(password_founds == 0)` implies that if your program doesn't find a password it will remain in an infinite loop.
Than you have 5 for loops in the while and all of them modifies the var`password_founds` so you have to trace the changes if you want to check the passwords.
I recommend you to insert the 5 checks in a separate unique function.